# program header не показывает данных

Tags: linux, c, elf

В file записывается весь исполняемый файл. Начало в write_file_new. Почему то program header из file не показывает данных. Почему то все параметры равны нулю.

```
static void elf64_copy_elf_header ( char *dump, const char *file ) {
    Elf64_Ehdr *elf = ( Elf64_Ehdr * ) file;
    Elf64_Ehdr *nelf = ( Elf64_Ehdr * ) dump;

    memcpy ( nelf->e_ident, elf->e_ident, EI_NIDENT );

    nelf->e_type = elf->e_type;
    nelf->e_machine = elf->e_machine;
    nelf->e_version = elf->e_version;
    nelf->e_entry = elf->e_entry;
    nelf->e_phoff = elf->e_phoff;
    nelf->e_shoff = elf->e_shoff;
    nelf->e_flags = elf->e_flags;
    nelf->e_ehsize = elf->e_ehsize;
    nelf->e_phentsize = elf->e_phentsize;
    nelf->e_phnum = elf->e_phnum;
    nelf->e_shentsize = elf->e_shentsize;
    nelf->e_shnum = elf->e_shnum;
    nelf->e_shstrndx = elf->e_shstrndx;
}

static void elf64_copy_program_header_num ( Elf64_Phdr *nphdr, const Elf64_Phdr *phdr, char *dump, const char *file ) {
    printf ( "phdr->p_type: %d\n", phdr->p_type );
    printf ( "phdr->p_flags: %d\n", phdr->p_flags );
    printf ( "phdr->p_offset: %ld\n", phdr->p_offset );
    printf ( "phdr->p_vaddr: %ld\n", phdr->p_vaddr );
    printf ( "phdr->p_paddr: %ld\n", phdr->p_paddr );
    printf ( "phdr->p_filesz: %ld\n", phdr->p_filesz );
    printf ( "phdr->p_memsz: %ld\n", phdr->p_memsz );
    printf ( "phdr->p_align: %ld\n", phdr->p_align );
    nphdr->p_type = phdr->p_type;
    nphdr->p_flags = phdr->p_flags;
    nphdr->p_offset = phdr->p_offset;
    nphdr->p_vaddr = phdr->p_vaddr;
    nphdr->p_paddr = phdr->p_paddr;
    nphdr->p_filesz = phdr->p_filesz;
    nphdr->p_memsz = phdr->p_memsz;
    nphdr->p_align = phdr->p_align;

    char *in = &dump[nphdr->p_offset];
    const char *out = &file[phdr->p_offset];

    memcpy ( in, out, nphdr->p_filesz );
}

static void elf64_copy_program_header ( char *dump, const char *file, long unsigned int size, long unsigned int num ) {
    const Elf64_Ehdr *elf = ( Elf64_Ehdr * ) file;
    const Elf64_Phdr *phdr = ( Elf64_Phdr * ) file + elf->e_phoff;
    Elf64_Phdr *nphdr = ( Elf64_Phdr * ) dump + elf->e_phoff;

    for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        elf64_copy_program_header_num ( &nphdr[i], &phdr[i], dump, file );
    }
}

static void elf64_copy_section_header_num ( Elf64_Shdr *isc, Elf64_Shdr *osc, char *dump, const char *file ) {
    isc->sh_name = osc->sh_name;
    isc->sh_type = osc->sh_type;
    isc->sh_flags = osc->sh_flags;
    isc->sh_addr = osc->sh_addr;
    isc->sh_offset = osc->sh_offset;
    isc->sh_size = osc->sh_size;
    isc->sh_link = osc->sh_link;
    isc->sh_info = osc->sh_info;
    isc->sh_addralign = osc->sh_addralign;
    isc->sh_entsize = osc->sh_entsize;

    char *in = &dump[isc->sh_offset];
    const char *out = &file[osc->sh_offset];

    memcpy ( in, out, osc->sh_size );
}

static void elf64_copy_section_header ( char *dump, const char *file, long unsigned int size, long unsigned int num ) {
    Elf64_Ehdr *elf = ( Elf64_Ehdr * ) file;
    Elf64_Shdr *isc = ( Elf64_Shdr * ) dump + elf->e_shoff;
    Elf64_Shdr *osc = ( Elf64_Shdr * ) file + elf->e_shoff;

    for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        elf64_copy_section_header_num ( &isc[i], &osc[i], dump, file );
    }
}

static void elf64_write_file_new ( const char *file, long unsigned int size, const char *new_file ) {
    Elf64_Ehdr *elf = ( Elf64_Ehdr * ) file;

    char *dump = calloc ( size, 1 );

    elf64_copy_elf_header ( dump, file );
    elf64_copy_program_header ( dump, file, elf->e_phentsize, elf->e_phnum );
    elf64_copy_section_header ( dump, file, elf->e_shentsize, elf->e_shnum );

    int fd = open ( new_file, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU );
    write ( fd, dump, size );
    close ( fd );
}
```

Я сделал утилиту, которая показывает где разные данные.

```
file: new size: 952
file: ../asm/test size: 952
00 01
идентичны 64 0x40 байт
```

Показывает что в файле new идентичны только elf header. Потом в новом файле 0x00, а в /asm/test 0x01. То есть данные есть, но они почему-то не показываются. Вот вывод.

```
4000b0: mov eax, 4
4000b5: mov ebx, 1
4000ba: lea ecx, ds:6000d8
4000c1: mov edx, DWORD PTR ds:6000e5
4000c8: int 0x80
4000ca: mov eax, 1
4000cf: mov ebx, 0
4000d4: int 0x80
4000d6: ret
int 0x0
phdr->p_type: 0
phdr->p_flags: 0
phdr->p_offset: 0
phdr->p_vaddr: 0
phdr->p_paddr: 0
phdr->p_filesz: 0
phdr->p_memsz: 0
phdr->p_align: 0
phdr->p_type: 0
phdr->p_flags: 0
phdr->p_offset: 0
phdr->p_vaddr: 0
phdr->p_paddr: 0
phdr->p_filesz: 0
phdr->p_memsz: 0
phdr->p_align: 0
```

И с помощью другой утилиты можно посмотреть hex данные.

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________
file: new size: 952
file: ../asm/test size: 952
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________
00000000: 7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000010: 02 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00 b0 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 : 02 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00 b0 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 
00000020: 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000030: 00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 02 00 40 00 06 00 05 00 : 00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 02 00 40 00 06 00 05 00 
00000040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 
00000060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : d7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 
00000080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : d8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 00 60 00 00 00 00 00 
00000090: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : d8 00 60 00 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 
000000b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : b8 04 00 00 00 bb 01 00 00 00 8d 0c 25 d8 00 60 
000000c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 00 8b 14 25 e5 00 60 00 cd 80 b8 01 00 00 00 bb 
000000d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 00 00 00 00 cd 80 c3 00 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 
000000e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 72 6c 64 0a 00 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: Утилитку не надо, `man cmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы везде используете сложение указателей, но получаете указатель на другую структуру :

```
( Elf64_Phdr * ) file + elf->e_phoff; ==>
(( Elf64_Phdr * ) file) + elf->e_phoff; ==>
(( Elf64_Phdr * ) file) [ elf->e_phoff ] ==> Elf64_Phdr номер elf->e_phoff
```

А нужно было смещение байтовое :

```
( Elf64_Phdr * ) (file + elf->e_phoff);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А это я и не заметил.